# How come I can't check if object-node is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I do a while-loop through an array with the following in it:

```
    if(typeof currMenu.menu !== undefined){
      console.log(currMenu.menu)
      currMenu = currMenu.menu[currDefault]
    }
```

I console.log undefined and get the error  Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined for the second row.

I expect the conditional to stop this. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`typeof`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof) **always** returns a string. A string value is never equal to `undefined`. Compare to the string `"undefined"` instead.